# Similarity Scores between SQL tables

Tags: classification, nlp, similarity, cosine-distance

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get started on a project.

I have two separate databases, one is a "Template" db and the other is "Content" db. For each table in the Content db, I want to be able to identify which table in the Template db it is most similar to. In terms of similarity, I only care about structure, meaning the table name, column names, and column types.

Because each table can have a different structure, I'm not sure how to set this up.

My current way of thinking is to vectorize the table name, column names, and col types, and then to do a cosine similarity score of each table in Content to each table in Template.

Does that approach make sense? What can I read up on to learn more about how to do this?

Thanks